# send input text value with file by js/ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am following [Adam tut](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP), Now I add text fields like this first name and last name. How can I send text value with file through js/ajax to php?

*Below is the form and js.*

**HTML Code**

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
     <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
     <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;">          </progress>
     <h3 id="status"></h3>
     <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

**Javascript code**

```
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Append text field values like formdata.append("text1", text1);